# How do I use A1 style reference with ExcelReference in Excel-DNA

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I want to write to a specific cell. I can do this easily if I use ExcelReference like:

```
        var refB1 = new ExcelReference(0, 0, 1, 1,"Sheet1");
        refB1.SetValue("My text");
```

But I would also like to specify cell like "B1". Something like:

var refB1 = new ExcelA1Style("B1","Sheet1");

ExcelReference does not appear to allow that option. Is there something else I should use?

I tried documentation but it is not very intuitive to me.

Comment: `ExcelReference` doesn't support `A1` style. Which context are you in? For example, are you inside an Excel function, or inside of a Ribbon handler?

Comment: I am inside of an Excel function